# Like button error, but it works after 7-12 days on each post

Tags: button, facebook-like

When I publish a new post on my site (http://kalaziagi-reiki.hu) the Like Button doesn't work on it, just after a few days later (about 7-12 days).

Look at this:
This post published at october 19, and the like button works on it:
[post at oct. 19.](http://kalaziagi-reiki.hu/2011/10/buddha-tanitasa-ii/)
And this post published at october 20, and it get an error:
[post at oct. 20.](http://kalaziagi-reiki.hu/2011/10/buddha-tanitasa-iii/)

The error message:
"The content you're trying to share includes a link that's been blocked for being spammy or unsafe: Body of an error/warning message. Title is: Sorry, this post contains a blocked URL. For more information, visit the www.facebook.com/help. If you think you're seeing this by mistake, please let us know: /help/contact.php?show_form=block_appeal."

I contacted with them many times, but the problem has still existed. I can share all of my post on facebook, the opengraph is good at each post - i checked them with the Facebook debugger at: developers.facebook.com/tools/debug.

What can I do to get work the Like button at each fresh post? Have you ever meet something like this problem? Thanks for any advice about this weird error!

Answer (score 0):

yeah I get usually this problem then I change the Apps id/ URL of site which we for like plugin
Actually FB ban the site  and apps id